# Arguments needed for MSBuild Task SVNCommit

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-task

We currently use MSBuild task to call on subversion commands. 
eg. `<SvnCommit  Message="Automated build server checkin" ToolPath="$(SvnPath)" Targets="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)"/>`

The issue is that it forces subversion command "svn ci"  to use switches  --non-interactive --no-auth-cache for our builds.

Does anyone know of  any arguments that I can use in the MSBuild task `<SVNCommit ... >` to get rid of switches --non-interactive --no-auth-cache from being used?

Thx.

Answer (score 0):

According to the most full and self-describing [documentation](https://github.com/loresoft/msbuildtasks/blob/master/Source/MSBuild.Community.Tasks/Subversion/SvnClient.cs) you can easily change any command line parameter. In your particular case you should add two args to the call

```
<SvnCommit Message="Automated build server checkin" 
           ToolPath="$(SvnPath)" 
           Targets="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)"
           NonInteractive="false"
           NoAuthCache="false"/>
```

PS: [their test](https://github.com/loresoft/msbuildtasks/blob/master/Source/MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Tests/Subversion/SvnCommitTest.cs) shows that those two args is really used by default.

Comment: I get the below errors druing builds when using those arguments. error MSB4064: The "NonInteractive" parameter is not supported by the "SvnCommit" task. Verify the parameter exists on the task. error MSB4064: The "NoAuthCache" parameter is not supported by the "SvnCommit" task. Verify the parameter exists on the task. Can u advise?